# pep8 (D103) I need docstrings for my unit test functions too?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Perhaps im not defining my pytests right but im seeing this:
[image]

Does pep8 demand a docstring for each unit test function too? I cant find pep8 docs specific to this, wondering if pep8/flake8 is unit test aware?

I have many tests so this might be kind of a mess to have docstrings, but maybe I should have fewer tests with many asserts instead of many small tests?

For example I have specific tests like:

```
test_method_one_returns_x_if_y_invalid()
test_method_one_returns_z_if_y_valid()
```

But perhaps it should be more like:

```
test_method_one_validates_y()
... then assert both cases in this single method
```

So if I have big tests with many cases grouped under them docstrings would be more feasible. Does pep8 or another convention have anything to say about this?

Comment: You unit test driver, such as `nose` or `python -m unittest` will take the first line of the docstring of each test and display that when a test fails, in addition to the test name. This can be really helpful, as it takes the pressure off naming many methods with almost identical test processes.

Comment: can someone explain why this was downvoted so I know why I should not be asking it here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [PEP-8 document](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) says:

> sometimes style guide recommendations just aren't applicable

Here, the recommendation in question is:

> Write docstrings for all public modules, functions, classes, and methods. Docstrings are not necessary for non-public methods, but you should have a comment that describes what the method does.

I'd argue that tests are not public modules in the sense of this recommendation, even though a test files *technically* is a module that *could* be imported and its contents are *technically* public. This just isn't the case.

The *intention* for using docstrings is that you know how to call the function. But test functions are never called directly. There's a secondary task of documenting the contents of the function (although normal comments also do the job). However, test functions often have very long and self-documenting names, so this is less of a concern.

Keeping tests somewhat tidy is legitimately important, so it can make sense to run flake8 or other linters over the test code as well. But since testing is a different context from normal code, some values are different. E.g. it is important that tests are independent, less important that tests are DRY. And whereas unused functions indicate a bug in normal code, this is normal in test code.

I would advise one of the following approaches:

- exclude tests from linting, e.g. via a configuration file or with `# flake8: noqa` comments. However, this is a fairly drastic approach.
- disable just this lint within the file, e.g. with `# noqa: D103` comments. However, I'm not sure if flake8 allows you to disable a lint for the entire file, or just for the current line.

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing completely with @amon. To answer his doubt on whether you can disable specific checks for a file:

Yes you can ignore checks per file using `per-file-ignores` in your `.flake8` config.
I gave an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72889403/flake8-d103-missing-docstring-in-public-function-for-unit-tests/72889404#72889404) how you can prevent this D103 code from showing up in your testing code.